# ¿Cómo conectar Delphi 2010 a Oracle utilizando dbExpress?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, delphi, delphi-2010

Por medio de `Toad For Oracle` me puedo conectar a la base de datos `oracle` sin problema alguno, de igual forma desde una versión antigua de Delphi utilizando **Borland Database Engine (BDE)**. Ahora estoy tratando de conectar `Delphi 2010` a esta base de datos.

Para esto utilizo el componente `TSQLConnection` de `dbExpress`, elijo Driver Oracle y agrego

- Database
- UserName
- PassWord

A continuación la configuración del componente en el frm

```
object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
    ConnectionName = 'OracleConnection'
    DriverName = 'Oracle'
    GetDriverFunc = 'getSQLDriverORACLE'
    LibraryName = 'dbxora.dll'
    Params.Strings = (
      'DriverName=Oracle'
      'Database=DESARROLLO'
      'User_Name=MyUsuario'
      'Password=MyPass')
    VendorLib = 'oci.dll'
    Left = 368
    Top = 48
  end
```

Al tratar de abrir la conexión en tiempo de diseño aparece el Mensaje

> (Cannot load oci.dll library (error code 126)).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al abrir en tiempo de ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Intentos de solución 1:**

Agregar la ruta de oracle a library/path (Tools > Options, en Environment Options > Delphi Options > Library-Win32, agregar en Library Path la ruta: C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN).

**Rta**: El error continua.

**Intentos de solución 2:**

Copiar:

- dbxora.dll
- oci.dll

Pegar en

- C:\Windows\System32\

**Detalles**: Copiar oci.dll de la carpeta de Oracle "C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\oci.dll" y dbxora.dll de la carpeta donde se instaló Delphi por defecto (C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\bin) y pegar en C:\Windows\System32

**Rta:** Aparece un nuevo error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Herramientas:**

- SO: Windows 7 Ultimate 32 Bits
- Base de Datos: Oracle 11g V 11.2.0.1.0 64 Bits
- Delphi 2010
- Toad For Oracle 10.1.6.3